# JSON input Datetime not formatting correctly in excel using Pandas Excelwriter

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I am trying to read in json into a dataframe in Pandas and then output the df to excel using pandas ExcelWriter.  I am getting mixed outputs in excel.  Both of the datetimes formats in the json are YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.sssZ.  For example, 2020-04-23T07:39:51.918Z.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


with open('simple_json_test.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data = map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), data)
data_json_str = "[" + ','.join(data) + "]"
df = pd.read_json(data_json_str)

print (df.dtypes)

# Write the dataframe to excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('simpleJsonToExcelTest.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, header=True, sheet_name='Pandas_Test',index=False)
writer.save()
```

I get the following error when I run my code: "*ValueError" Excel does not support datetimes with timezones.  Please ensure that the datetimes are timezone unaware before writing to Excel*"

I output the df.types() to see what types are the colums:

```
Triggered Time            object
action_time       datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

It's weird since the both seem to be the same format in the json.  Here is the json

```
{"action_time":"2020-04-23T07:39:51.918Z","Triggered Time":"2020-04-23T07:39:51.900Z"}
{"action_time":"2020-04-23T07:39:51.918Z","Triggered Time":"2020-04-23T07:39:51.900Z"}
{"action_time":"2020-04-23T07:39:51.918Z","Triggered Time":"2020-04-23T07:39:51.900Z"}
{"action_time":"2020-04-23T07:39:51.918Z","Triggered Time":"2020-04-23T07:39:51.900Z"}
```

I made the following updates to the code and got it to run successfully, however the output in the excel file is not the same.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


with open('simple_json_test.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data = map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), data)
data_json_str = "[" + ','.join(data) + "]"
df = pd.read_json(data_json_str)

print (df.dtypes)
df['action_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['action_time'],errors='coerce',utc=True)
df['action_time'] = df['action_time'].apply(lambda a: datetime.strftime(a, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%f")[:-3])
df['action_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['action_time'], errors='coerce',format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%f')

print (df.dtypes)

# Write the dataframe to excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('simpleJsonToExcelTest.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, header=True, sheet_name='Pandas_Test',index=False)
writer.save()
```

I'm new to pandas, so some of the things I have tried, i don't fully understand and may be incorrect.  The output in the excel file is:

**action_time** column is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
**Triggered Time** is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.sssZ

| action_time | Triggered Time |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-04-23 07:39:51 | 2020-04-23T07:39:51.918Z |

Triggered time is how i want the format to be (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.sssZ). I need to preserve the milliseconds.  Looks like action_time in excel is an actual date field, while triggered time is not.

I even tried converting the datatype of the action_time to object and that didn't work.  I'm stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why "action_time" and "Triggered Time" are parsed with different types but replacing the space in "Triggered Time" converts both to `datetime64[ns]`. Maybe someone else can explain that part.

Anyway, with that in place you can format the datetime objects in Excel like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


with open('simple_json_test.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data = map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), data)
data = map(lambda x: x.replace('Triggered Time', 'Triggered_Time'), data)

data_json_str = "[" + ','.join(data) + "]"
df = pd.read_json(data_json_str)

print (df.dtypes)

# Write the dataframe to excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('simpleJsonToExcelTest.xlsx',
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        datetime_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000')

df.to_excel(writer, header=True, sheet_name='Pandas_Test', index=False)

# Widen the column for visibility.
worksheet = writer.sheets['Pandas_Test']
worksheet.set_column('A:B', 25)

writer.save()
```

Strip the timezone from the dates if needed. I didn't have to do that. Output:

[image]

See also [Formatting of the Dataframe output](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-output) in the XlsxWriter docs.

Comment: Thanks @jmcnamara.  I am still getting thee same error on the 'df.to_excel(writer...)' line.

Comment: In that case you will need to remove the timezone information from the datetime objects. Something like: `df['action_time'] = df['action_time'].dt.tz_localize(None)` (for both columns).

Comment: Actually, i had commented the ```df[]``` statements out mistakenly since they were not in your code example.

Comment: If you have a new question you should post it as a new question with an example that demonstrates what is working and what isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your help @jmcamara.  Really appreciate it.